# How to find the total numbers of possible rows in a flat pyramid with a set number of stones

Tags: calculus

i'm not so good with maths, so this maybe is a very simple question but I don't really know where to start to solve it.

I want to find the possible total layers of a pyramidal scheme with a set number of "stones".
At each layer, the pyramid would have one more "stone", like so :

```
------S
-----S-S
----S-S-S
---S-S-S-S
```

I need to know how I could calculate the max numbers of layers possible to have, starting from the top, with different number of whole stones, like 52 or 87.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flat pyramid is a triangle and these are the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), $T_n=\frac 12n(n+1)$

If you have $T_n$ and want $n$ you get it by $n=\frac 12(-1+\sqrt{8T_n+1})$.  If you want to find the number of rows including partial ones, round up.